# how to set client name in libtorrent

Tags: c#, c++, libtorrent-rasterbar

i have develop torrent program in client and using rutorrent for seeding file. im using plug-in peer in rutorrent to monitor number client using my torrent application. but in Client tab only show Unknown(xxxx). how to set name using libtorrent. shell will show in in client.
[image]

Comment: rutorrent/rtorrent is based on [libTorrent-rakshasa](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/), not [libtorrent-rasterbar](http://libtorrent.org/) A bit confusing naming there...

Comment: my client torrent using libtorrent-rasterbar to build. im looking for all document but not find how to set name that will show my application name in client. if im using bittorrent or utorrent download my file .torrent. in tab client will show name bitorrent or utorrent not show Unknow like my application. so you can show me hot to set name like this using libtorrent-rasterbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through client_test.cpp then you'll see you need to pass in details of the useragent in the settings structure. You need to do this before you start a session and your client name needs a / after it ie:

```
 settings.user_agent = "My Own Client/" LIBTORRENT_VERSION;
```